# Passing a json list through a servlet and print out with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

I have to pass a json list like this

```
{
"Airports": [

{ "Name":"value" ,
"City":"value",
"Latitude": "value",
"Longitude": value" }, so on...
]
}
```

and print out in jquery but unfortuntately I didn't get the expected result. Here is it the code. the servlet pass an object called `list` but I don't get it into the success function. Can you suggest me where I wrong?

```
success: function(data){

                $.each(data.result.list, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#airportscities')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",value)
                    .text(value)); 
                });       
            }
```

This is an example of the json list I'm trying to print out

```
[{"name":"Amendola","country":"Italy","city":"Amendola","latitude":"41.541392","longitude":"15.718083"},{"name":"Crotone","country":"Italy","city":"Crotone","latitude":"38.997225","longitude":"17.080169"},
```

Comment: you aren't getting into the success function because you're getting an error. You can catch that error the same way you're catching the success. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
success: function(data){
   var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
   $.each(jsonObj.Airports, function(key, value) {   
       $("#airportscities").append($('<option>', {
               value:value[1],
                text:value[1]
         }));
     });       
}
```

from this,city value will be populated in drop down list